# A query about editorial decision to remove amusing foot shooting incident related comment

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

This post used to have a very funny exchange in the comments where somebody suggests "just try deleting the table" and someone else responded "why not also try shooting yourself in the foot".

[How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

I'm interested in the editorial decisions that have lead to the removal of these comments, personally they made me smile and I think they conveyed an important message about taking due care with data decisions.

I feel these kind of edits remove some of the personality of the site.  Thoughts?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, so their deletion is not really an "editorial" decision. Material that should be kept should go in posts, where they are more likely to survive. However yes, we are keen on technical writing here, and it sounds like the conversation would have had to be translated a bit in order to preserve it in an answer.

Comment: Sarcastic comments arguably at someone else's expense doesn't really fit with the professional tone we're going for here.

Comment: You might smile, but the next person reading that might feel how SO is so aggressive, especially for non-native speakers who could interpret that sentence *literally*...

Comment: Just an FYI, the comment being discussed has been deleted for over a year.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's personality we could all do without. The expression "shooting yourself in the foot" is quite enough expense of the other person — doubling up the sarcasm with a "why not also try" is just seriously unnecessary. It may be funny to some, but it wouldn't be unreasonable for the one being the butt of the joke to take it as a slight on them, if they don't share the same sense of humor.